# Call 2 methods on page load

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction

I have a VF page render as PDF, now I want to call two methods the second one "generateImageDoc" must start when the first "loadData" is finished, and both must run during page load. I'm trying to do that whit this code:

```
<apex:page controller="CrashDossierPDFController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:variable var="customerLogo" value="{!customerLogo}"/>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="loadData" action="{!loadData}"  status="myStatus" oncomplete="generateImageDoc();"/>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        // start the process that create the crash images
        window.onload = onload;
        function onload{
            loadData();
        }
    </script>
```

But the methods seem not starting at all. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should add rerender in your actionFunction

Comment: Hi, I edited my code like this : <apex:form id="actiononload">
<apex:actionFunction name="loadData" action="{!loadData}"  status="myStatus" oncomplete="generateImageDoc();" reRender="actiononload"/>
</apex:form> , but I have the same result

Comment: generateImageDoc() is a JavaScript function? If it is apex, you need to call another actionFunction to invoke it

Comment: no it's an apex method that I want to invoke when loadData ends, in this way I have to separate transaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing rerender in your `apex:actionFunction`, without which whole page would reload.

Your JavaScript code looks fine.

Have a dummy `apex:OutputPanel` for rerendering.

I suspect your second function call is a apex method, in that case you can call another `apex:actionFunction` to invoke it. Because **`oncomplete`** only accepts JavaScript function.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="dummy"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="loadData" 
    action="{!loadData}"  
    status="myStatus" 
    oncomplete="callGenerateImageDoc();"
    rerender="dummy"/>

<apex:actionFunction name="callGenerateImageDoc" 
    action="{!generateImageDoc}"
```

### rerender="dummy"/>

**Added**:

Change JavaScript function to:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        loadData();
    }
</script>
```

You're missing parenthesis in both the function call.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems in your code.

1. Your JavaScript. It has error in it. See your Console.
2. As @Rahul pointed out, you've not added `reRender` attribute to your `actionFunction`.

Use **jQuery** or simply use JavaScript code as @Rahul suggested and it will work. Refer below for example:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!loadData}" name="loadData()" reRender="panel1" oncomplete="generateImageDoc();" />
     <script>
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

        j$(document).ready(function() {
            alert('load');
            loadData();


        });
     </script>
```

Comment: Hey @Rohit, i don't think that is the issue over here. the JavaScript method should work fine. I could be wrong though :)

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes. He needs to add reRender condition in `actionFunction `too

Comment: yup. have added it already. thanks for pointing out! Keep up the good work mate.

Comment: @RahulSharma There is problem in his JavaScript code too. I tried his code on my developer org and it doesn't work. He should try something like this :`window.onload = function() {load1();};`

Comment: window.onload = function onload() { alert('hi'); } - this works. He is just missing a parenthesis in his function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apex page **action** to fulfill your requirement. In Action method use first action and from the first action you can call the second action.

```
<apex:page controller="CrashDossierPDFController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" action="{!loadData}">

Public void loadData(){
 your functionality...
 then call the second function 
 generateImageDoc();
}
```

Comment: I can't because I need to separate transcation, in the first one I make a callout and in the second one I save a record

Comment: @L.benedettini did you tried changing script the way I posted as an answer?

Comment: Yes  Rohit Mourya , thank you but did not solved the problem the methods seem not start at all, I put System.Debug in the first rows to inspect, but nothing

Comment: L.benedettini, Did you add attribute reRender each time you used  <apex:function>? .Without reRender attribute, this tag will be totally ignored.